# Программа для фокусировки веб-камеры

Tags: поиск-программ, web-камера

Подскажите, есть ли программы для веб-камеры, которыми можно настроить программный автофокус, чтобы фон был размыт, а мое чудесное лицо было четче четкого ?

Comment: Вроде, скайп так умеет делать. А можно ли это поведение как-то сделать так, чтобы оно применялось и на другие программы, где это фичи нет?

Answer (score 0):

[Snap Camera](https://snapcamera.snapchat.com/) - в ней надо выбрать, картинка какой камеры будет модифицироваться, а она сама создаёт в системе виртуальную камеру, которую могут использовать остальные приложения.

Размытие фона она вроде тоже умеет, хотя не уверен. Из того, что точно есть:

- замена фона на виртуальный
- добавление виртуальных элементов на лицо
- замена лица на что-либо

Я использовал замену фона на виртуальный (при этом лицо остаётся). Вообще, виртуальные фоны довольно сложно найти (по крайней мере, у меня что-то не задалось - гораздо больше добавления каких-то элементов на лицо или замены лица), но [вот эти](https://lensstudio.snapchat.com/creator/VGclBN04bmWO26jleNU6AA) мне понравились, особенно дерево `UPennBIOPond3` - оно не только хорошо смотрится, но ещё и довольно пёстренькое, что делает менее заметными косяки определения границ лица в случаях, когда часть фона комнаты остаётся.

Вообще, качество определения зависит от освещения. И от наличия наушников на голове - у меня в наушниках днём получилось несколько хуже, чем пока я всё настраивал без них ночью перед созвоном - там было почти идеально. Так что лучше настраивать хотя бы за сутки заранее, чтобы понимать освещение и что с ним можно сделать.

А ещё можно превратиться в летающий над пляжем ананас - `Pineapple` [отсюда](https://lensstudio.snapchat.com/creator/RZEkhB4Nnh7d6lz_-anLQQ).

Найденные фоны можно добавлять в избранное и использовать их оттуда. Если есть ссылка на фон на сайте, то чтобы найти его в программе надо скопировать в её поиск название фона.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Почему-то ругань в некоторых приложениях, что камера используется другим приложением-(

Comment: @iluxa1810, в винде камеру, в отличие от микрофона, одновременно может использовать только одно приложение. Хотя сейчас именно на этой камере я заметил, что прокатывает несколько одновременно - как минимум OBS и Zoom. В любом случае, не думаю, что это проблема камеры.